# Geometry Problem Math Olympiad

Tags: geometry

This question is from a recent math olympiad I participated in. I have yet to solve this particular problem.

In $\triangle ABC$, $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC$ into two equal halves. $E$ is the midpoint of $AC$. $BP$ is the tangent drawn from $B$ on the circumcircle $\triangle DEC$. If $AB=18$, $AC=24$, $BP=12$ then $BC=a\sqrt b$. Find the value of $a+b$.

I know $AB/AC=BD/CD$, so $4BD=3CD$.
I have used the cosine rule on $\angle BAD$ and $\angle DAC$, and set them equal to each other which gave me the following equation, $AD^2= 432+4BD^2-3CD^2$.
I feel like if I find a equation with $BP$ and $AD$, I can figure out what $BC$ is. Can anyone give me a hint ?

Comment: Are you familiar with 1) Angle bisector theorem, 2) Power of a point? If yes, how can we apply those? If no, I recommend you look them up.

Comment: $D$, $E$, $C$ are collinear points because they all belong to the side $BC$. Am I wrong ? If I am right, $DEC$ is not a triangle, so there does not exist its circumcircle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two long for a comment... (Calvin Lin already gave enough hints.)

[Power of a point](https://brilliant.org/wiki/power-of-a-point/#:%7E:text=points%20on%20the%20circle%20have,the%20circle%20have%20positive%20power.) with respect to a circle... Tangent-secant case: In our problem, it reads as $BP^2=BD.BC$. You already found that $BD=3k$ and $DC=4k$. And since $BP=12$, we have $12^2=3k.(3k+4k)\implies$$ 144=21k^2\implies k=\frac{4}{7}\sqrt{21}.$ Hence, $BC=7k=4\sqrt{21}=a\sqrt{b}\implies a+b=25.$ The question should have said that $b$ is square-free.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the 'Secant-Tangent Power Theorem'. That makes this problem really easy.